# Prevent duplicated code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this test:

```
    it "redirects him to vice" do
      get :show
      uri_request_1 = Addressable::URI.parse(response.redirect_url)
      redirects_to_vice_1 = uri_request_1.host == "vice.com"

      get :show, relative_path: "/Fun/Facts.html"
      uri_request_2 = Addressable::URI.parse(response.redirect_url)
      redirects_to_vice_2 = uri_request_1.host == "vice.com"

      assert redirects_to_vice_1 && redirects_to_vice_2
    end
```

It has a lot of repetition. How can I shorten this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about adding a helper method:

```
def assert_redirection_to(host)
  assert Addressable::URI.parse(response.redirect_url) == host
end
```

With such a method you could change your tests to:

```
describe 'without parameters' do 
  it 'redirects to vice.com' do
    get :show
    assert_redirection_to 'vice.com'
  end
end

describe 'with parameters' do 
  it 'redirects to vice.com'
    get :show, relative_path: '/Fun/Facts.html'
    assert_redirection_to 'vice.com'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[:show], [:show, relative_path: "/Fun/Facts.html"]].each do
  |args|
  get(*args)
  assert Addressable::URI.parse(response.redirect_url).host == "vice.com"
end
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others